# How to reuse WPF styles?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a style that I'm using on several columns of a Datagrid.

```
<DataGridTextColumn ...>
  <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter .../>
      <Setter .../>
   </Style>
  </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

I'm replicating the above style code for all columns. Is there some way to do this without replicating the code?

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with? Even the most basic WPF tutorial and documentation mentions reuse of things like styles, templates, etc. via resources. Have you heard of that? Are you trying to use that and having some specific problem? Possibly you might find one of these useful, if your question is about something more than just basic resource use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293213/wpf-style-reuse, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993675/how-to-parameterize-reuse-xaml-control-style, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630292/why-cant-i-style-a-datagridtextcolumn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in a `ResourceDictionary` or the parent control's(the `Window` or `DataGrid`) `Resources`:

```
<Style x:Key="TextColumnEditStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter .../>
    <Setter .../>
</Style>
```

And you can reuse it like this:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGridTextColumn EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource TextColumnEditStyle}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource TextColumnEditStyle}"></DataGridTextColumn>
</Datagrid>
```